# Apply transparency only to some windows with FluxBox

Tags: transparency, fluxbox

I'm new to Fluxbox, I've adopted it this week end. (I only knew Kde, Gnome, and Unity lately).

Is there a possibility to apply transparency only to windows that match a criteria ?
for example a regular expression or an exact matching against an application name.

In deed, I do want the transparency in the Terminals... in the task manager... but  I don't want it on other application. (Chromium for instance).

Could I set up something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had not read enough the documentation. In the fluxbox [feature list](http://fluxbox.org/features/), at the first entry:

*"One of the most underestimated - although one of the most powerful features - is the apps-file. With this file it is possible to set application-specific parameters for dimension, decoration, default workspace to open on, stickyness and much more. It will let you manipulate almost every setting for any window or application. The best way to learn about it is to visit the wiki-site for the apps-file."*

It allows to configure specifically the interface, based on the application. It looks like it does exactly what I wanted. I'm gonna try this.